# how to get google results source code with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I want to get some google search results in my website,I know I can get with curl,php but its limited daily for same ip adress. and I dont want to use google search api because its also has limit. So I think I can get with jquery ajax but I m a bit new on that,I am fed up with this problem.
here is my code, its will be always error because of jsonp format, but maybe still there is a way for catch html source code. I see source code comes to my browser but I cant take it like object.I tryed xhr.responseText etc but its gives  also SyntaxError, still I cant get.
if you can suggest to me any other ways or if you have any idea with below code please share with me.
Thanks before now

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://www.google.com.tr/search?q=ercan", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 

    success:function(json){
         // I know its wont never succes, because google gives source in html format
         alert("Success");
    },
    error:function(xhr){
         //I want to get source code html here, but its giving always parse end syntax error I cant get it
         console.log(xhr);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your only choices are to use the API or server side bridge script. You cannot do cross domain AJAX calls if the server doesn't support JSONP or CORS. There's also a commercial version of the API which allows you to increase the limit of requests you could send.